# why are my rows and columns slightly to the left with react-bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap to make my website responsive. I've used react-bootstrap before and I always encounter this problem: when setting my rows and cols they're slightly to the left and not centered, as if there were no margin. I've used class names to center the whole row, but it's just not responding like I want it to. This is my code and there is no css going on yet

```
const Projects = () => {
      return (
        <div className='Projects' >
          <Row className='mt-5 pt-5 my-auto'>

            <Col lg={4}> <img src={image} alt=""/> </Col>
   
            <Col lg={4}> <img src={image} alt=""/> </Col>
            
            <Col lg={4}> <img src={image} alt=""/> </Col>
  

          </Row>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga05H.jpg) It's slightly to the left and has some space on the right. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap grid must be wrapped in a [`<Container>`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#container):

```js
const Projects = () => {
      return (
        <Container className='Projects' >
          <Row className='mt-5 pt-5 my-auto'>

            <Col lg={4}> <img src={image} alt=""/> </Col>
   
            <Col lg={4}> <img src={image} alt=""/> </Col>
            
            <Col lg={4}> <img src={image} alt=""/> </Col>
  

          </Row>
        </Container>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response ! It does look a bit better, but it's still slightly uneven and it drives me crazy